# Failed to compile react project in my computer

Tags: reactjs

New react file showing compile error
I just make a react file and run without any typing ...
its says this:

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'C:\Users\papai\OneDrive\Desktop\Web_Dev_Project\#30JS Project(React)\dram-
pad\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?
protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&l
ive-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\papai\OneDrive\Desktop\Web_Dev_Project\#30JS 
Project(React)\dram-pad'

ERROR in Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 
'C:\Users\papai\OneDrive\Desktop\Web_Dev_Project\#30JS Project(React)\dram-
pad\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?
protocol=ws%3A&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=3000&pathname=%2Fws&logging=none&overla
y=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=true&l
ive-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\papai\OneDrive\Desktop\Web_Dev_Project\#30JS 
Project(React)\dram-pad'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Fix this error.plese

Comment: I wonder if the `#` in your project name is causing an error. Try starting a new project, but just use lowercase `a-z` characters in the project name and don't have spaces or parentheses in the name either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are saving your project to a OneDrive location. There is most likely a problem when accessing the cloud storage.

I recommend creating a new project in a local directory.
For example 'C:\Users\username\Documents'

Comment: No , I changed the location but it shows the same error

Comment: What compiler are  you using? @PapaiMistry